# Cannot create hot stream from Queue

Tags: java, spring-mvc, project-reactor

I have the following rest controller, which receives requests, transforms them into JSON strings and puts them into a concurrent queue.
I would like to make a Flux out of this queue and subscribe to it.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
@RestController
public class EventController {
    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private final FirehosePutService firehosePutService;
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> events = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private int batchSize = 10;

    @Autowired
    public EventController(FirehosePutService firehosePutService) {
        this.firehosePutService = firehosePutService;

        Flux<String> eventFlux = Flux.create((FluxSink<String> sink) -> {
            String next;
            while (( next = events.poll()) != null) {
                sink.next(next);
            }
        });

        eventFlux.publish().autoConnect().subscribe(new BaseSubscriber<String>() {
            int consumed;
            List<String> batchOfEvents = new ArrayList<>(batchSize);

            @Override
            protected void hookOnSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
                request(batchSize);
            }

            @Override
            protected void hookOnNext(String value) {
                batchOfEvents.add(value);
                consumed++;

                if (consumed == batchSize) {
                    batchOfEvents.addAll(events);
                    log.info("Consume {} elements. Size of batchOfEvents={}", consumed, batchOfEvents.size());
                    firehosePutService.saveBulk(batchOfEvents);
                    consumed = 0;
                    batchOfEvents.clear();
                    events.clear();

                    request(batchSize);
                }
            }

        });
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/saveMany", produces = "text/html")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> saveMany(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> allRequestParams) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Map<String, String> paramValues = allRequestParams.toSingleValueMap();
        String reignnEvent = mapper.writeValueAsString(paramValues);
        events.add(reignnEvent);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you use `poll` method. It is not blocking and returns `null` if queue is empty. You loop collection until first `null` (i.e. `while (next != null)`, so your code exits loop almost immediately because queue is empty on start. You must replace `poll` with `take` which is blocking and will wait until element is available.

Secondly, `hookOnNext` is invoked when the event is removed from the queue. However, you are trying to read events again using `batchOfEvents.addAll(events);`. Moreover, you also clear all pending events `events.clear();`

I advise you to remove all direct access to `events` collection from `hookOnNext` method.

---

Why do you use Flux here at all? Seems overcomplicated. You can use plain thread here

```
@Autowired
public EventController(FirehosePutService firehosePutService) {
    this.firehosePutService = firehosePutService;

    Thread persister = new Thread(() -> {
        List<String> batchOfEvents = new ArrayList<>(batchSize);

        String next;
        while (( next = events.take()) != null) {
            batchOfEvents.add(value);

            if (batchOfEvents.size() == batchSize) {
                log.info("Consume {} elements. Size of batchOfEvents={}", consumed, batchOfEvents.size());
                firehosePutService.saveBulk(batchOfEvents);
                batchOfEvents.clear();
            }
        }
    });
    persister.start();

}
```